# Best approach to add multiple data to a column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

For example, I have `Users` and `Projects` tables.

Multiple users can be members of a project. How do I insert multiple users into the `members` column of the `Projects` table?

Do I separate by comma like: "John, Alex, Hanna"?

I'm a beginner in MySQL, sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a `Users` column in `Projects` table. Search for `relational database model`.

Comment: Apology accepted ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Got it! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defiantly need another table.
It should look like this

Name: UserProjects

Field: UserId

Field ProjectID

Those 2 fields should be primary keys (dual primary id). If you want to go down the route of 'soft deletes' then add a status column which you'll set to 0 if you delete it. Also look up insert on update for mysql.

Trust me this is the way to go. Using a delimiter field or something will only give you problems later down the line.

Comment: Here is a link to a insert on duplicate key update - that I was on about.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists